# Android - Show new view

Tags: android, button, view

I am starting now to study Android. I came from iOS development. How can I do for show a new view by clicking a button in Android?

Thanks

Comment: New View? New activity (Window on screen)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an on click listener for your button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // as asked by Pepi, what view are you planning to display??
        }
    });
```

Write the code inside depending on what has to be displayed

Comment: A simple view, not an Activity.

Comment: @Andrea Lufino :
It can be done in a large number of ways depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve. 
You can add a child view to any layout using the `addView()` function. 
eg `TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("hello");
linearlayout.addView(tv);`

While adding you can specify the layout parameters and also various other parameters depending on which layout you are adding the view to.

An easier way would be to make the view initially invisible and change the visibility on click .

Answer (score 1):

if you are going for a simple view not a activity. as you said in comment then you should use LayoutInflater on click or any event you want

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View myNewViewToadd = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_view, null);
myParentView.removeAllViews();
myParentView.addView(myNewViewToadd, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(v == btn_login)
        {
            Intent login=new Intent(this,Login.class);
            Activity.this.startActivity(login);

        }
         else if(v == btn_register)
        {
            Intent register=new Intent(this,Register.class);
            Activity.this.startActivity(register);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     startActivity(new Intent("[package name].NEWVIEW"));
  }
 });
```

Then you need to create a new activity section in your manifest file with the name .[what's the name for your new class] and for the action you need to import your "[package name].NEWVIEW" and the .MAIN below this need to be rewrite to .DEFAULT
Hope it helped.